# How do I access the map?

Tags: divine-divinity

I've been playing the 2002 game, Divine Divinity, on Steam (Amazing game btw).  Throughout the early part of the game many NPC's state that they're marking information on your in-game map - however, I can only seem to access a tiny mini-map.  Does anyone know how/if there is a larger map or if the mini-map can be traversed in a way to view a larger map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on your journal and then on the second button of the panel.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's actually configurable, you can set the map (in the "keys" option) to any button, or a combination of buttons (mine is "CTRL + W"), whenever I push that combo, the fullscreen map will show up, pushing that combo again will close it. It's way quicker that way, you don't have to open the journal and then move to the map.